# I have installed TensorFlow in my Windows but I get an Error when I try to import it in my Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

import tensorflow as tf

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

---

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\importlib_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

SystemError:  returned a result with an error set

---

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: numpy.core._multiarray_umath failed to import

---

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import

Answer (score 2):

This happens because jupyter is not picking the tensorflow installed in that particular environment.

Solution for the above is:

```
conda activate <your-env>
conda install jupyter
pip install tensorflow
jupyter notebook
```

This should work fine now, as you have installed jupyter using the conda within the environment.

Also, I can see in your post that there is problem with numpy.
As a precaution do:

```
pip install -U numpy
```

or reinstall after uninstall

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy
```

or the 3rd way:

```
pip install --ignore-installed numpy
```

Remember to do after activating your environment.

This should sort it